# Delete all *.Zip files older than today using Windows batch file

Tags: batch-file

Assuming you must use a Windows batch file, *(not `powershell`)*, and one wants to delete all files ending in `.zip` that are in the current active directory. How to do this?

All attempts so far are failing:

```
forfiles -p "C:\temp\test" -s -m *.zip -d 1 -c "cmd /c del *.zip"
```

For this it says

> ```
> ERROR: No files found with the specified search criteria.
> ```

Comment: Open a Command Prompt, enter `ForFiles /?` and read the usage information, _also paying some attention to the `/C` option section_.

Answer (score 2):

As suggested in my comment, your problem could easily be solved by reading the usage information for your command, *(available when entering `FORFILES /?` at the Command Prompt)*.

Based on your questions criteria, "`delete all files ending in .zip` that are in `the current active directory`":

You don't need to use the `/P` option because as stated in the usage information, "`The default folder is the current working directory (.)`".

There is nothing in your question regarding recursing subdirectories of the current directory, so the `/S` option which "`Instructs forfiles to recurse into subdirectories`" is not required.

For the `/D` option you are looking for files with a last modified date less than yesterday, *i.e. "`the current date minus "dd" days`"*, `/D -1`.

Because you're wanting to delete files in the current directory, there's no need to use the "`Full path of the file`", `@path`, so what you need is the "`The name of the file`", `@file`.

```dos
FORFILES /M *.zip /D -1 /C "CMD /C DEL @file"
```

Answer (score 1):

You did not mention anything about subdirectories or windows version so I'm assuming somewhat.  You have an old version syntax.  In Windows 7 and further the syntax changed a little bit.

For windows 7:

```
forfiles /P "C:\temp\test" /S /M *.zip /D -1 /C "cmd /c del @path"
```